# Windows 10 Creators Update touchpad mouse frequently freezes

Tags: windows-10, mouse, freeze, touchpad

I just got a Lenovo X1 Carbon yesterday, and installed the Windows 10 Creators Update on it.

For the last 24 hours, I've been seeing the mouse touchpad randomly freezes for like a couple seconds. This would happen quite frequently, maybe every 5 seconds or so.

There is no heavy programs running on the computer, as I just got it.

Wondering if anyone else has seen this problem? Does anyone think it could be due to the Creators update?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I performed a Windows Update, and then restarted the computer, and the problem seems to be gone for now. (FWIW, I did try to restart the computer before, but that didn't fix it then).</strike>

Will close this question for now.

Looks like the mouse freezes are back. It's also worth noting that the computer (i.e. the keyboard) is still responsive during this freeze. So it seems that only the mouse is affected.